Stack tried to find libgmp then failed, even with no dependencies at all
I use nix-darwin and have enabled nix in ~/.stack/config.yaml.
Earlier today I did a sudo nix-collect-garbage -d then many things begin to break.
Minimum reproducible example:
stack new mwe
cd mwe
stack build

mwe> configure (lib + exe)
dyld[39413]: Library not loaded: /nix/store/lac8fhiz0pmif1bmrkkry3w4slc9wg47-gmp-with-cxx-6.3.0/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
  Referenced from: <0F2264AA-4505-36E1-A379-2BC393A601C5> /Users/futar/.stack/setup-exe-cache/aarch64-osx-nix/Cabal-simple_CKvAmRb3_3.10.3.0_ghc-9.6.6
  Reason: tried: '/nix/store/lac8fhiz0pmif1bmrkkry3w4slc9wg47-gmp-with-cxx-6.3.0/lib/libgmp.10.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/nix/store/lac8fhiz0pmif1bmrkkry3w4slc9wg47-gmp-with-cxx-6.3.0/lib/libgmp.10.dylib' (no such file), '/nix/store/lac8fhiz0pmif1bmrkkry3w4slc9wg47-gmp-with-cxx-6.3.0/lib/libgmp.10.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgmp.10.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)

Error: [S-7282]
       Stack failed to execute the build plan.

       While executing the build plan, Stack encountered the error:

       [S-7011]
       While building package mwe-0.1.0.0 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
       ...
       Process exited with code: ExitFailure (-6)

A problem that I have never seen before this garbage collection.
Adding gmp as a nix package in stack.yaml does not help and result in the same error message. Neither will nix-shell -p gmp.
nix:
  enable: true
  packages:
    - gmp

I do have gmp-with-cxx here. Why can't stack find it?
Why a wrong hash was used?
% ls /nix/store/*-gmp-with-cxx-6.3.0/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
/nix/store/lm1rva8c2649y4lys3d406s9ldicv8qv-gmp-with-cxx-6.3.0/lib/libgmp.10.dylib


Deleted ~/.stack/setup-exe-cache, stack clean --full and then stack build works. Not sure if I have to do this every time after nix-collect-garbage.
